# Google Places API: Search based on coordinate bounds instead of radius

Tags: google-places-api

I want to search the Places API by specifying bounding latitudes and longitudes instead a single latitude/longitude coordinate and a radius.

As an example, I'd like to be able to query the API for all results within the graticule bounded by 60N in the south, 61N in the north, 1E to the west and 2E to the east.

Is this possible?

Comment: Will you always be using the same bounds for all search requests?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like the Place Search API exposes this capability.

You can work around this with a little math by providing a radius **r** such that the approximately square area you are interested in with side length **s** is inscribed by the circlular search area. This will provide you with a superset of the results you are looking for which you can then filter in the application layer.

Say I'm interested in the approximately square area centered on lat[60.5], lng[0.5] where the square has side length 500 meters.

The diagonal of the square is:

```
(2 * s^2)^(1/2)
(2 * 500^2)^(1/2) ~= 707
```

The diagonal of this square is the diameter of the circumscribing circle. To get the radius, we divide by 2:

```
707 / 2 ~= 353
```

In this manner you can approximately accomplish your task.